# how to write on a RFID card using a phidget RFID SUT1024?

Tags: python, rfid, phidgets

I'm trying to write a value into a RFID card using the Phidget RFID SUT 1024. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find a working code for this reader and chatGPT didn't give me a working code either. The only thing I was able to do is to read the card.

Here's code I have right now:

```
import time
from Phidget22.Devices.RFID import RFIDTag

from Phidget22.Devices.RFID import RFIDTextRecord
from Phidget22.Devices.RFID import *
from Phidget22.PhidgetException import *
from Phidget22.Phidget import *
from Phidget22.PhidgetException import *
from Phidget22.Net import *

def on_tag(self, tag, protocol):
    print("Tag value: ", tag)

def on_lost(self, tag, protocol):
    print("Tag lost")

def write_number(rfid, number):
    rfid.setAntennaEnabled(True)
    message = RFIDTag()
    text_record = RFIDTextRecord()
    text_record.Text = str(number)
    message.Records.append(text_record)
    rfid.writeNDEFMessage(message)
    rfid.setAntennaEnabled(False)


def read_number(rfid):
    tag = rfid.getTag()
    tag.setProtocol(RFIDProtocol.PHIDGETS)
    data = tag.readTag().decode()
    if data:
        return int(data)
    else:
        return None



def subtract_number(rfid, number):
    current_number = read_number(rfid)
    if current_number is not None:
        new_number = max(current_number - number, 0)
        write_number(rfid, new_number)
        return new_number
    else:
        return None


def main():
    try:
        rfid = RFID()
        rfid.setOnTagHandler(on_tag)
        rfid.setOnTagLostHandler(on_lost)
        rfid.openWaitForAttachment(5000)
        while True:
            print('1. Write a number to the tag')
            print('2. Read the previously written number on the tag')
            print('3. Subtract a number from the previously written number on the tag')
            choice = input('Enter your choice: ')
            try:
                if choice == '1':
                    number = int(input('Enter a number to write to the tag: '))
                    write_number(rfid, number)
                    print('Number {} written to tag'.format(number))
                elif choice == '2':
                    number = read_number(rfid)
                    if number is not None:
                        print('Number on tag: {}'.format(number))
                    else:
                        print('No number found on tag')
                elif choice == '3':
                    number = int(input('Enter a number to subtract: '))
                    new_number = subtract_number(rfid, number)
                    if new_number is not None:
                        print('Number subtracted from tag. New number: {}'.format(new_number))
                    else:
                        print('No number found on tag')
                else:
                    print('Invalid choice')
            except Exception as e:
                print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
    except PhidgetException as e:
        print("Phidget Exception %i: %s" % (e.code, e.details))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like some assistance with my problem.

Thanks,